# How to interpret $\mathcal{L}(Y\Bbb{1}_B) = \Bbb{P}(B)\mathcal{L}(Y|B)+\Bbb{P}(B^C)\delta_0$

Tags: probability-theory

I understand that if $v = \mathcal{L}(Y|B)$, then $ v(S) = \mathbb{P}(Y\in S|B)$.

When I read the conditional probability and expectation part, it says
$\mathcal{L}(Y\Bbb{1}_B) = \Bbb{P}(B)\mathcal{L}(Y|B)+\Bbb{P}(B^C)\delta_0$. How to interpret this?

If let $u=\mathcal{L}(Y\Bbb{1}_B)$, what is $u(A)$? is it $\mathbb{P}(Y\Bbb{1}_B \in A)$? or $\mathbb{P}(Y\Bbb{1}_B(A))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $u(A)=\mathbb{P}(Y1_B \in A)$ of the definition of law. Second:
$$0\in A \to u(A)=\mathbb{P}(B^C)+\mathbb{P}(B,Y\in A)$$ and $$0\notin A \to u(A)=\mathbb{P}(B,Y\in A),$$ concording with the posibilites for $Y1_B$.